# An $F$-open set, which is affine, is an affine $F$-variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I have a subtle question about varieties.  I've been trying to make sense out of this stuff for over a year.  My references are the two books both called *Linear Algebraic Groups* by Springer and Borel.

Here is the nonintrinsitic situation: Let $X$ be a closed set in $\mathbb{A}^n$, and suppose that the ideal $I$ corresponding to $X$ is generated by polynomials with coefficients in $F$.  Then the coordinate ring $k[X] = k[T_1, ... , T_n]/I$ acquires an "$F$-structure," which is to say an $F$-subalgebra, namely $$F[X] := F[T_1, ... , T_n]/I \cap F[T_1, ... , T_n]$$ which is finitely generated and when tensored with $k$ over $F$ becomes $k[X]$.  We acquire on $X$ a subtopology of "$F$-open sets" i.e. subsets of $X$ whose complement in $X$ is the zero set of some collection of polynomials in $F[X]$.  To each $F$-open set $U$ in $X$, it is possible to define an $F$-subalgebra $\mathcal O_X^F(U)$ (not necessarily finitely generated over $F$) of $\mathcal O_X(U)$ which when tensored with $k$ over $F$ becomes $\mathcal O_X(U)$, in such a way that if we identify $\mathcal O_X(X)$ with $k[X]$, $\mathcal O_X^F(X)$ is just $F[X]$.

Here is the intrinsic situation: An *affine $k$-algebra with $F$-structure* is a finitely generated, reduced $k$-algebra $A$, together with a finitely generated $F$-subalgebra $A_0$, such that $A = k \otimes_F A_0$.  The corresponding variety $X = \textrm{Spm } A$ acquires the structure of an *affine $F$-variety*, which means the following:

1 .  A subtopology of $F$-open sets of $X$, namely an open set $U \subseteq X$ is $F$-open if and only if $X - U$ is the zero set of an ideal which is extended from $A_0$ (which is a weaker assertion than the ideal corresponding to $X - U$ itself being extended from $A_0$!).

2 .  On each $F$-open set $U$ in $X$, an $F$-subalgebra $\mathcal O_X^F(U)$ of $\mathcal O_X(U)$ (not necessarily finitely generated over $F$) defined as follows: let $U = D(f_1) \cup \cdots \cup D(f_m)$ be any open cover of $U$ by *principal $F$-open sets*, i.e. $f_i \in A_0$.  Each localized ring $A_f = \mathcal O_X (D(f))$ has a finitely generated $F$-subalgebra $(A_0)_f$ which when tensored with $k$ over $F$ becomes $A_f$.  Noting that $D(f_i) \cap D(f_j) = D(f_if_j)$, the sheaf condition gives us an exact sequence

$$ 0 \rightarrow \mathcal O_X(U) \xrightarrow{\phi} \prod\limits_i A_{f_i} \xrightarrow{\psi} \prod\limits_{i,j} A_{f_if_j}$$

and $\mathcal O_X^F(U)$ is defined as the preimage under $\phi$ of $\prod\limits_i (A_0)_{f_i}$.

This definition of $\mathcal O_X^F(U)$ is independent of the choice of cover, and in particular we have $\mathcal O_X^F(D(f)) = (A_0)_f$ for $f \in A_0$ and $\mathcal O_X^F(X) = A_0$.  We also have $\mathcal O_X(U) = k \otimes_F \mathcal O_X^F(U)$.  Then $\mathcal O_X^F$ is a sheaf on $X$ with the topology of $F$-open sets.  $\blacksquare$

One can define a morphism of affine $F$-varieties in a natural way, so that the category of "affine $k$-algebras with $F$-structure" is antiequivalent to that of affine $F$-varieties.

Now, here's my question.  Let $(X, \mathcal O_X)$ be an affine $F$-variety (as defined above), and suppose that $U$ is an $F$-open set which happens to be affine.

> Can we say that the affine variety $(U, \mathcal O_{X|U})$ is naturally an affine $F$-variety?

Ideally I would want these things to happen:

1 .  $\mathcal O_X^F(U)$ is finitely generated as an $F$-algebra.  (so that $(U,\mathcal O_{X|U})$ acquires the structure of an affine $F$-algebra via the ring $\mathcal O_X^F(U)$, and in particular acquires rings $\mathcal O_{X|U}^F(V)$ for every $F$-open subset $V$ of $U$, such that $\mathcal O_{X|U}^F(U) = \mathcal O_X^F(U)$)

and assuming (1) holds,

2 .  An open set $V \subseteq U$ is $F$-open in $U$ if and only if it is $F$-open in $X$

and assuming (1) and (2) hold,

3 .  $\mathcal O_X^F(V) = \mathcal O_{X|U}^F(U)$

These three conditions seem to be a tacit assumption by both Borel and Springer in their books.  For example, on page 13 of Springer, he writes in the definition of an arbitrary $F$-variety "an affine $F$-open set has the structure of an affine $F$-variety."

However, even condition 1 seems like it need not hold.  In general, if $A_0$ is an $F$-algebra, just because $k \otimes_F A_0$ is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra does not mean that $A_0$ is finitely generated as an $F$-algebra (e.g. if $k$ has infinite transcendence degree over $F$, take $A_0 = F[x_i]$ where $x_i$ is a transcendence basis for $k/F$).

Comment: You're aware that over 50 years ago Grothendieck thought of a much better way of doing all this, right? Grothendieck would reject $X$ completely if you want to work over $F$, and instead work with the prime ideals of the $F$-algebra.

Comment: Your last comment seems to me to be wrong. The abstract tensor product $k\otimes_F A_0$ is not finitely-generated if $A_0$ is a polynomial ring in infinitely many variables, even if you are regarding the variables as elements of $k$.

Comment: My gut feeling is that you should never be considering non-finitely-generated algebras in any sort of foundational question like this. You might end up considering algebras which you ultimately prove are finitely-generated, but non-finitely-generated algebras shouldn't be playing any role here, as you can see if you think about things from the Grothendieck point of view.

Comment: I know of no example of a non-finitely-generated algebra over a field which becomes finitely-generated when you tensor it up to a bigger field (one might exist, but none spring to mind, and it might never happen). You know that if both X and Y happen to be subsets of Z, then X tensor Y isn't just the subthing of Z generated by X and Y, right? It can be much bigger, and just surject onto it (like your $F[x_i]$ above).